# Output squares using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to accomplish taking an input number, for ex 8 and have it output all of the squares up to 64. so 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64. I want to do it without using the exponent operator. I have run into a problem where my loop is just jumping straight to 64 and skipping the other squares.

```
limit = input('Enter a value for limit: ')
limit = int(limit)
square= (limit)*(limit)
ctr = 1
while ctr <= (limit):
    print(ctr, end=' ')
    ctr = (square) + 1
print("limit =", square )
```

Comment: You *probably* want `ctr = ctr + 1`.  You may *also* want to **calculate** other squares *besides* just `limit*limit`.

Comment: `ctr = (square) + 1` exceeds `limit` on the first iteration since `square = limit**2`. So your `while ctr <= (limit):` loop breaks.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I want the square variable to be inside the loop so that it finds the squares of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and then stops at 64

Comment: @Astonishing: You never calculate those squares, though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat what do you mean?

Comment: @Astonishing: You are only printing `ctr`.  I assume you want to print `ctr*ctr` (you know, the square).  Also 65 is not less than (or equal to) 8.

Comment: (Also, I know you're just learning python, but this can all be done in a single line using list comprehension: `[i*i for i in range(1, limit+1)]`)

Comment: @RocketHazmat i dont want it to be only for 8. I just used that as an example. Im trying to make it so the user can input any number and have the program output the squares

Comment: @Astonishing: Yeah, but you are only outputting `ctr`, not `ctr`-squared.  Also `square+1` is ***not*** less-than-or-equal-to `limit`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Now I understand what you are saying. I just needed to fix the ctr*ctr. Makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter(`ctr`) increment part is wrong. When you do `ctr = (square) + 1`, you are making it more then the limit in the first iteration itself. For example, lets say the limit is 8, which means square is 64.

Now you want your loop to run while ctr is less than equal to limit.

You start with `ctr=1` and then in the first iteration itself, its updated to `ctr = 64 + 1`.
That's the problem.

The loop counter as per your requirement should increment by 1.
So you need to change it to `ctr = ctr +1` or `ctr += 1`.

And you need to print ctr*ctr instead of just ctr as you want squares.